# Setting text in angular multiselect tab

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, multi-select

I use an angular 2 multiselect. When user clicks it an API gets called in the background and displays options in the drop-down. But as the API is taking time to give response the dropdown is showing as "No data available" and then showing the response when it recieves. How to change that default text to something like "Loading..." ?

Comment: declare a variable loading = false, make it true after clicking on tab. again make it false after successfully loaded... {{loading? 'Loading...': 'No data found'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace "No data available" with "Loading..." as default text. When the API is called and fetches response as you might be overriding dropdown options with response that will replace "Loading...". And If API fetches 0 response then you should replace with "No data available".

If you show "No data available" before just calling API then that means you are saying user that dropdown does not have any value but it brings value later. By this you are conveying wrong idea about the drop-down which is not aligned with UX what you need, If you agree.

Below solution is a hack, may be you want to rewrite as per requirement because I am assuming your code looks somewhat as below but I used along with solution:

html:

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
  [placeholder]="text"
  [data]="dropdownList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings"
  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

ts:

```
//Declare settings

this.dropdownSettings = {
      singleSelection: false,
      idField: 'id',
      textField: 'text',
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
      noDataAvailablePlaceholderText: "Loading...",
      itemsShowLimit: 3,
      allowSearchFilter: true,
      limitSelection: 2
    };
  }
onClick(){
  // then api call here will replace the string most probably
}
```

Comment: Hi Shoma, thanks for your reply. But my question itself is how to do it? How to change the " No data" to "Loading" as it's the default text I'm not sure where to change it.

Comment: I tried the  "content" css-property but that didn't work there.

Comment: I have edited my answer with solution or say hack, may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

There was a drop-down setting property called "noDataLabel" 
which did the trick.. it's value is used when no data is available.

Comment: Do you mean "noDataAvailablePlaceholderText" ?